# Wrapper not working / page scaling

Tags: html, css

I have another problem.
I made a #wrapper in my page to control width of content, but...
It's not working on bigger screens than 1366px.

Tested it on 1920 screen and in debugger page has total width of wrapper (not 1920 but 1244px (wrapper width)).
Same problem was on 4k TV - Page was "scaled" to wrapper width.
It looks like full width of page was wrapper and "width: 100%" on body/sections were ignored.

Any idea where is problem?
Without !important on wrapper its same, max/min width not working. Changing units to vw not working also. Removing/changing meta tag not working. There is no other tags that overwrite wrapper. Styles has been cleared by SCSS Reset at start.
What Im doing wrong?

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .aaa {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 1224px !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
     <body>
        <section class="aaa">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <h2>content</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
     </body>
    </html>
```

it should be like that:

[-margin-[-wrapper 1224px-]-margin-]

[------------------1920px-----------------]

And its like that on 1920px resolution:

[--wrapper 1224px----]

[-1224px in debugger-]

Even if screen resolution is 1920px

There is link to cleared page: [www.xileo.pl](http://www.xileo.pl)

And img from 4k screen:[image]

As you can see, there is 3840px screen, where wrapper is scaled to 3840px and its not 1224px with margins.
I want it to be on 1224 px with margins.

Comment: Provide a complete working example (jsfiddle.net for example).

Comment: I really do not understand. You have wrapper width declared to 1224px and content inside it. On every screen resolution it would be 1224 px because you declared so, no matter of body or html width

Comment: In code, wrapper is in other div with 100% width. So on 1920px width screen, wrapper should keep site at 1224px, and on sides should be space (by margin: 0 auto; on wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.aaa {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#wrapper {
    max-width: 1224px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Provide a jsfiddle if this is not helping you.

*Edit added a screen from near 4k resolution, your screenshot is not from true 4k device, it is maybe scaled or something else is going on so you need to figure that one with some kind of debuging. All else behaving as expected. You might have something else in ur css files that maybe override your code, so you partial code you posted is working as expected.

[image]

Comment: As I see this is my code without !important, and with closing tag (that was copy&paste mistake).

Comment: there is more than that, max with used and important classes removed, so translated into scss. max-width is the property you need.

Comment: Eddited main post, there is link and photo from 4k screen.

Comment: Your screenshot is not from 4k monitor. Here is how it looks on 4k (2 monitors - extended)

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
https://jsfiddle.net/8yt3fp0k/ the css works, definitely something wrong with the SCSS, probably another #wrapper is definned somewhere else out of the snipped provided.

css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.aaa {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1224px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Just copy&paste mistake, im ussing scss in normal.

Comment: put a jsfiddle with scss then and maybe explain better what you exactly need, tested my code and works fine. width never exceeds 1224px.

Comment: it should be like that:

[-margin-[-wrapper 1224px-]-margin-]
[-----------------1920px-------------------]

And its like that on 1920px resolution:
[-wrapper 1224px------]
[-1224px in debugger-]
Even if screen resolution is 1920px

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be different on bigger resolution, than change width:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.aaa {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1224px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1224px) {
 #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

New answer after question edit and posted link to original website:

You have this rule:

```
.index .main-page .main .main-box .about-us {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 370px;
}
```

This gives the upper text block a very large right padding which diminishes its width. You can erase that rule to strecht `about-us` across the full width of the `wrapper`.

However, if you want `.about-us` to be narrower and horizontally centered inside the first `wrapper`, change that rule to

```
.index .main-page .main .main-box .about-us {
    width: 1224px; /* any value you like */
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also, note two more things:

1.) `wrapper` has the 1224px limitation and is also used inside the other sections. So if you want the subsequent section (the one with the four text blocks)  to stretch across a wider screen, change the `width` and `max-width` values in the wrapper rule

2.) You are using `wrapper`  more than once. But it is bound to an `ID`, which should only be used once per page. So you should change `#wrapper` to `.wrapper` in the CSS and *all* `id = "wrapper"` attributes in your HTML elements to `class = "wrapper"`

Comment: Eddited main post, there is link and photo from 4k screen.

Comment: please note my completely changed answer

Comment: Ignore content inside wrapper. Everything here is about sections (100% width of screen) and wrapper (1224px) inside those sections.

On bigger screens it should be MARGIN [WRAPPER] MARGIN.
But its just [WRAPER] As you can see on screen from 4k screen (3800+px width).

It should work only with "margin: 0 auto" on wrapper, but it doesnt. 
All what I want is (for example for 1920px screns):
348px margin left + wrapper 1224px + 348px margin right 
total is 1920.



ad. ID's - true. Will fix it.

Comment: Look at your page in the developer tools: The wrapper *IS* 1224px wide, and it *is* centered by `margin: 0 auto`. The only thing which is not centered and not 1224px wide is that first text block, due to its `padding-right` (see my answer above). Also, don't  mix up device pixels (on a retina or 4K screen) and CSS pixels. Your display is 1920 CSS pixels wide, even if it's 3840 device pixels wide. The CSS rules define measurements in CSS pixels.

Comment: Im confused right now. Coz, on retina it looks as its intended.
But on laptop 1920x1080 it looks like on photo.

I know it should work Johannes, but now Im trying to figure why for someone its ok, and for someone other is not.